# How to setup environment to use two python addons package

Tags: python-2.7, module

I have a task to integrate several different python script into the project.
Let's say python_1 and python_2 script.

To run the python_1, I need to set up environment using
module add python/2.7-addons-argparse (otherwise, some module can't be imported)

To run python_2, I need to do the setup as
module add python/2.7-addons-jinja2.

I will call both python1 and python2 within a Makefile, "module add" within
the Makefile will change the build environment whose impact is big. So I would
like to set-up python environment ready and then proceed to the Makefile

Module add one package will override the previous one, how to use both addons packages?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I just set-up the env variable of PYTHONPATH to include both of the python/2.7-addons-argparse and python/2.7-addons-jinja2. Within the makefile, I first use the following string command to extract them
string(REGEX MATCH "[:^]/.*addons-argparse.*[$:]" ARGPARSE_PATH ${OLD_PYTHONPATH})
and 
string(REGEX MATCH "[:^]/.*addons-jinja2.*[$:]"JINJA2_PATH ${OLD_PYTHONPATH})

When I want to run python_1, I set it as:
 SET(ENV{PYTHONPATH} "${ARGPASE_PATH}:${OLD_PYTHONPATH}")
For python_2, I set it as:
SET(ENV{PYTHONPATH} "${JINJA2_PATH}:${OLD_PYTHONPATH}")
Then It's OK.